# How to convert a group of csv files to another group of csv files(with different filenames and format)?

Tags: python, string, bash, shell, text

I have some files, consisting of end of day stock data in the following format :

Filename: NYSE_20120116.txt

```
<ticker>,<date>,<open>,<high>,<low>,<close>,<vol>
A,20120116,36.15,36.36,35.59,36.19,3327400
AA,20120116,10.73,10.78,10.53,10.64,20457600
```

How can I create files for every symbol?
For example for the company A

Filename : A.txt

```
<ticker>,<date>,<open>,<high>,<low>,<close>,<vol>
A,20120116,36.15,36.36,35.59,36.19,3327400
A,20120117,39.76,40.39,39.7,39.99,4157900
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove the ticker column from the resulting files by altering the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to split the first file at record level, then route each row to a different file based on the value of the first field?

```
 # To skip first line, see later
 cat endday.txt | while read line; do
     # Careful with backslashes here - they're not quote signs
     # If supported, use:
     # symbol=$( echo "$line" | cut -f1 -d, )
     symbol=`echo "$line" | cut -f1 -d,`

     # If file is not there, create it with a header
     # if [ ! -r $symbol.txt ]; then
     #    head -n 1 endday.txt > $symbol.txt
     # fi
     echo "$line" >> $symbol.txt
 done
```

Not very efficient: Perl or Python would have been better.

If you have several files in a directory (mind you, you have to remove them yourself, or they will be processed again and again...), you can do:

```
 for file in *.txt; do
    echo "Now processing $file..."
    # A quick and dirty way of ignoring line number 1 --- start at line 2.
    tail -n +2 $file | while read line; do
       # Careful with backslashes here - they're not quote signs
       # If supported, use:
       # symbol=$( echo "$line" | cut -f1 -d, )
       symbol=`echo "$line" | cut -f1 -d,`

       # If file is not there, create it with a header
       # if [ ! -r $symbol.txt ]; then
       #    head -n 1 $file > $symbol.csv
       # fi
       # Output file is named .CSV so as not to create new .txt files
       # which this script might find
       echo "$line" >> $symbol.csv
    done
    # Change the name from .txt to .txt.ok, so it won't be found again
    mv $file $file.ok
    # or better move it elsewhere to avoid clogging this directory
    # mv $file /var/data/files/already-processed
 done
```

Comment: Is it possible to add an outer loop to this script so that I dont have to do it for every single source file?Thank you again.

Comment: I get the following message : Script started, output file is typescript , and then I have a small typescript file created in the folder.I am using bash shell with macos lion.

Comment: I fixed that (I had to type ./script).Now the error I am getting is './script: line 5: $symbol.txt: ambiguous redirect'

Comment: I think that the error has to do with trying to use the first line of the files, which has a completely different format.

Comment: Sorry, the first line was really there? I thought it was only a placeholder. My bad. Editing now

Comment: ...of course, new files (A.txt, etc.) must be created with the first line in place. Otherwise you can do, just before echo "$line":  "if [ ! -r $symbol.txt ]; then head -n 1 $file > $symbol.txt; fi" -- which will create the new file $symbol.txt with the first line of $file.

Comment: Thank you so much for the new script...but I am getting the following error when I run it : tail: *.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: I fixed that last error by removing the ok extension from the txt files but now I am getting a new error : ./script: line 6: $symbol.txt: ambiguous redirect

Comment: ...this should only ever happen if you run the script in a directory which has NO text files at all (I should have added an existence test). In that case, "for file in *.txt" does not get expanded, and $file is assigned the value "*.txt" instead of 20120730.txt, 20120731.txt and so on in sequence. Consequently, tail tries to find *.txt and can't. Nothing is generated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13367/discussion-between-lserni-and-skiabox)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.I've added the question to the python category too.